# Why is list or array filled completely with duplicates of one object in each iteration of 'for' loop?

Tags: java, arraylist, reference

(It turns out, the code here is excess, the question could be made shorter, as seen in the first answer of John Kugelamn. It's all about creating objects and not references to them.)

I'm at a total loss. It looks like the for() cycle's gone mad. Or it's just me going...

As far as I know, it must do sth iterably, step by step, but looks like all iterations work simultaneously.

here is the code:

```
static ArrayList<float[][]> carCrd = new ArrayList<float[][]>();
String[] sarr = {"train", "\"train::car_1::chassis\"",
  "\"train::car_2::chassis\"", "\"train::car_3::chassis\"",
  "\"train::car_4::chassis\"", "\"train::car_5::chassis\"" };

//function for parsing some big String into a list of
//phys. coordinates (loc and rot) for each model in sarr
ArrayList<float[][]> parse(. . .){
  float[] loc = {0, 0, 0};
  float[] rot = {0, 0, 0, 0};
  CoordTrack.carCrd.clear();
  carCrd.ensureCapacity(sarr.length);

  //for each String (model) in sarr parse corresp. coordinates:
  for(String par: sarr){
    sc = new Scanner(. . .);
    loc[0] = Float.valueOf(sc.next());
    . . .
    rot[3] = Float.valueOf(sc.next());
    sc.close();

    //let's print loc and rot for each iteration to see that they're 
    //correctly different:
    System.out.println("x: " + loc[0] + " y: " + loc[1] + " z: " + loc[2]);
    System.out.println("x: " + rot[0] + " y: " + rot[1] + " z: " +
      rot[2] + " w: " + rot[3]);

    //append the resulting List
    CoordTrack.carCrd.add(new float[][] { loc, rot });

    //now let's print the size of the list and it whole
    //in each 'for' iteration:
    System.out.print(carCrd.size());
    for(float[][] sar: carCrd){
      System.out.println("x: " + sar[0][0] + " y: " + sar[0][1] +
        " z: " + sar[0][2]);
      System.out.println("x: " + sar[1][0] + " y: " + sar[1][1] +
        " z: " + sar[1][2] + " w: " + sar[1][3]);
      System.out.print("");
  }

  }


return(carCrd);
}
```

and the function gives this output:

```
x: 5.6086507 y: 96.49017 z: 4.2678218E-7
x: 7.454923E-7 y: -1.9659414E-7 z: -0.9956668 w: 0.092992336

1
x: 5.6086507 y: 96.49017 z: 4.2678218E-7
x: 7.454923E-7 y: -1.9659414E-7 z: -0.9956668 w: 0.092992336

x: 0.0 y: 0.0 z: 0.1
x: 0.0 y: 0.0 z: 0.0 w: 1.0

2
x: 0.0 y: 0.0 z: 0.1
x: 0.0 y: 0.0 z: 0.0 w: 1.0
x: 0.0 y: 0.0 z: 0.1
x: 0.0 y: 0.0 z: 0.0 w: 1.0

x: 0.13724202 y: -0.584103 z: 0.100000165
x: -5.220888E-7 y: -8.881327E-7 z: -0.062116615 w: 0.99806887

3
x: 0.13724202 y: -0.584103 z: 0.100000165
x: -5.220888E-7 y: -8.881327E-7 z: -0.062116615 w: 0.99806887
x: 0.13724202 y: -0.584103 z: 0.100000165
x: -5.220888E-7 y: -8.881327E-7 z: -0.062116615 w: 0.99806887
x: 0.13724202 y: -0.584103 z: 0.100000165
x: -5.220888E-7 y: -8.881327E-7 z: -0.062116615 w: 0.99806887

x: 0.16923165 y: -1.1832443 z: 0.10000184
x: -3.4203006E-7 y: -1.3052559E-6 z: 0.16753982 w: 0.9858653

4
x: 0.16923165 y: -1.1832443 z: 0.10000184
x: -3.4203006E-7 y: -1.3052559E-6 z: 0.16753982 w: 0.9858653
x: 0.16923165 y: -1.1832443 z: 0.10000184
x: -3.4203006E-7 y: -1.3052559E-6 z: 0.16753982 w: 0.9858653
x: 0.16923165 y: -1.1832443 z: 0.10000184
x: -3.4203006E-7 y: -1.3052559E-6 z: 0.16753982 w: 0.9858653
x: 0.16923165 y: -1.1832443 z: 0.10000184
x: -3.4203006E-7 y: -1.3052559E-6 z: 0.16753982 w: 0.9858653

x: 0.4568624 y: -1.7098008 z: 0.100002564
x: 3.1865994E-7 y: -2.2401466E-6 z: 0.48815113 w: 0.8727591

5
x: 0.4568624 y: -1.7098008 z: 0.100002564
x: 3.1865994E-7 y: -2.2401466E-6 z: 0.48815113 w: 0.8727591
x: 0.4568624 y: -1.7098008 z: 0.100002564
x: 3.1865994E-7 y: -2.2401466E-6 z: 0.48815113 w: 0.8727591
x: 0.4568624 y: -1.7098008 z: 0.100002564
x: 3.1865994E-7 y: -2.2401466E-6 z: 0.48815113 w: 0.8727591
x: 0.4568624 y: -1.7098008 z: 0.100002564
x: 3.1865994E-7 y: -2.2401466E-6 z: 0.48815113 w: 0.8727591
x: 0.4568624 y: -1.7098008 z: 0.100002564
x: 3.1865994E-7 y: -2.2401466E-6 z: 0.48815113 w: 0.8727591

x: 1.0100093 y: -1.9422312 z: 0.100003526
x: 3.6465533E-8 y: -1.9686745E-6 z: 0.7412199 w: 0.6712623

6
x: 1.0100093 y: -1.9422312 z: 0.100003526
x: 3.6465533E-8 y: -1.9686745E-6 z: 0.7412199 w: 0.6712623
x: 1.0100093 y: -1.9422312 z: 0.100003526
x: 3.6465533E-8 y: -1.9686745E-6 z: 0.7412199 w: 0.6712623
x: 1.0100093 y: -1.9422312 z: 0.100003526
x: 3.6465533E-8 y: -1.9686745E-6 z: 0.7412199 w: 0.6712623
x: 1.0100093 y: -1.9422312 z: 0.100003526
x: 3.6465533E-8 y: -1.9686745E-6 z: 0.7412199 w: 0.6712623
x: 1.0100093 y: -1.9422312 z: 0.100003526
x: 3.6465533E-8 y: -1.9686745E-6 z: 0.7412199 w: 0.6712623
x: 1.0100093 y: -1.9422312 z: 0.100003526
x: 3.6465533E-8 y: -1.9686745E-6 z: 0.7412199 w: 0.6712623
```

As we see, each time the list is not appended but completely overwritten.
Actually, when I iterate with int index in for() and when I use not List but an array, I get the same result.
Why?

or

Who is mad?..

Comment: why are u using static list?

Comment: Can you post a [complete example program](/help/mcve) that we can compile and run ourselves? It would help a lot if you could edit out the `...`s and make this a complete, self-contained program.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I suppose there was enough and even excess information, judging by your answer below)
also I use Gazebo with my own enviromental setting for simulating the animate, so you'd hardly be able to launch the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float[] loc = {0, 0, 0};
float[] rot = {0, 0, 0, 0};

...

CoordTrack.carCrd.add(new float[][] { loc, rot });
```

You're adding the same two arrays `loc` and `rot` over and over. `new float[][]` doesn't create a *copy* of those arrays, it uses *references* to them. Every entry in `carCrd` references the same two arrays.

You'll need to explicitly copy the `float` values each time you make the two-dimensional array.

Comment: @alexey, you could use `CoordTrack.carCrd.add(new float[][] { loc.clone(), rot.clone() });` to add fresh arrays to the `List`.

Comment: @msandiford and JohnKugelman thank you for fast replies, I'll check them later, here in Msk it's 3:30 am which isn't the best time.)
I think I understand the issue now.
Do you know where the details about references and copies in Java are explained deeper?

Comment: The advice about clone() method works well, thank you!